# Bundling Electron main script with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

I have an existing Electron app that I'm trying to import webpack into.

Here's the webpack config file I've created:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
        filename: "index.js"
    },
    target: "electron-main",
    externals: {
        "bufferutil": "bufferutil",
        "utf-8-validate": "utf-8-validate",
        "fsevents": "require('fsevents')", //https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload/issues/71#issuecomment-588988382
        "@analytics/segment":"require('@analytics/segment')"

    },
    node: {
        __dirname: true,
        __filename: false
    }
}
```

When I point Electron to the generated file, I get this error:

```
App threw an error during load
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I would assume this is a simple enough config but can't get it to work at all!

Comment: Where is this error originating from ?

Comment: @Seblor, it's one of the node modules I use. The offending lines are ```var fileSchema = 'file://';
  if (fileName.indexOf(fileSchema) === 0) {
    fileName = fileURLToPath(fileName);
  }
```